# Failed to dial target host "kong-proxy-service-external-ip:443": context deadline exceeded

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, kong, grpc-go, kong-ingress

I am trying to use Kong API Gateway with Using Ingress with gRPC but getting below error.

**Failed to dial target host "kong-proxy-service-external-ip:443": context deadline exceeded**

I am using minikube cluster for deplyment.

I followed all the steps mentioned here - **https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/guides/using-ingress-with-grpc/** but when I tried to run **grpcurl -v -d '{"greeting": "Kong Hello world!"}' -insecure $PROXY_IP:443 hello.HelloService.SayHello**
I got the error Failed to dial target host

If I use port forwarding on service with command **kubectl port-forward service/grpcbin 9001:9001** then this works so that mean the issue is somewhere with ingress or some configuration issue.

Request you to help me with this issue.